# Calculate acceleration and deceleration while traveling from A to B

Tags: python, math, time, distance, micropython

I am using code like the example below to simulate travel from one point to another.

The goal I want to achieve is have a realistic acceleration and deceleration at the beginning and end of trip regardless of the length of trip, while in the middle of the trip be going at max speed.

I want to make it so if the trip is short enough that the traveler never reaches max speed, they will merely speed up to midpoint of trip, then decelerate. This is necessary as this code will be used for travel between various distances.

```
import time

meters = 100000
traveling = True
meters_second = 0
max_meters_second = 1000
seconds = 0

while traveling:
    if meters <= 0:
        traveling = False
        meters = 0
        meters_second = 0
        seconds = 0
        print('you have arrived!')
    else:
        if seconds < 20:
            meters_second += 1
        elif meters < 10000:
            meters_second -= 1
        else:
            meters_second = max_meters_second
        meters -= meters_second
        seconds += 1
        print(f'dist to destination(m):{meters} M/s: {meters_second} time passed(s):{seconds}')
        time.sleep(1)
```

With this example, there is a sort of constant acceleration and deceleration at beginning and end of trip, but it doesn't work right.

This may be more of a math problem, but there's probably a variable I can include to make this easier that I am missing.

The output of current code:

```
meters to dest:99999 M/s: 1 time elapsed(s):1
meters to dest:99997 M/s: 2 time elapsed(s):2
meters to dest:99994 M/s: 3 time elapsed(s):3
meters to dest:99990 M/s: 4 time elapsed(s):4
meters to dest:99985 M/s: 5 time elapsed(s):5
meters to dest:99979 M/s: 6 time elapsed(s):6
meters to dest:99972 M/s: 7 time elapsed(s):7
meters to dest:99964 M/s: 8 time elapsed(s):8
meters to dest:99955 M/s: 9 time elapsed(s):9
meters to dest:99945 M/s: 10 time elapsed(s):10
meters to dest:99934 M/s: 11 time elapsed(s):11
meters to dest:99922 M/s: 12 time elapsed(s):12
meters to dest:99909 M/s: 13 time elapsed(s):13
meters to dest:99895 M/s: 14 time elapsed(s):14
meters to dest:99880 M/s: 15 time elapsed(s):15
meters to dest:99864 M/s: 16 time elapsed(s):16
meters to dest:99847 M/s: 17 time elapsed(s):17
meters to dest:99829 M/s: 18 time elapsed(s):18
meters to dest:99810 M/s: 19 time elapsed(s):19
meters to dest:99790 M/s: 20 time elapsed(s):20
meters to dest:98790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):21
meters to dest:97790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):22
meters to dest:96790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):23
meters to dest:95790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):24
meters to dest:94790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):25
...80 lines removed to reduce example size...
meters to dest:12790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):107
meters to dest:11790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):108
meters to dest:10790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):109
meters to dest:9790 M/s: 1000 time elapsed(s):110
meters to dest:8791 M/s: 999 time elapsed(s):111
meters to dest:7793 M/s: 998 time elapsed(s):112
meters to dest:6796 M/s: 997 time elapsed(s):113
meters to dest:5800 M/s: 996 time elapsed(s):114
meters to dest:4805 M/s: 995 time elapsed(s):115
meters to dest:3811 M/s: 994 time elapsed(s):116
meters to dest:2818 M/s: 993 time elapsed(s):117
meters to dest:1826 M/s: 992 time elapsed(s):118
meters to dest:835 M/s: 991 time elapsed(s):119
meters to dest:-155 M/s: 990 time elapsed(s):120
you have arrived!
meters to dest:0 M/s: 0 time elapsed(s):1
```

Comment: You accelerate for the first 20 seconds and then, unless you're close to the end, you go straight to max speed. That seems wrong. You want to accelerate as long as 'meters' is more than half the total distance and your speed is less than max speed (note that this can sometimes make you overshoot a bit). I would recommend making the intervals much smaller if you want to not overshoot

Comment: Spot on! And It looks like two two answers posted solve this problem. My issue is understanding how the math works. Will keep working on it to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly close to what you're looking for:

```py
import time

meters = 10000
max_diatance = meters
distance = 0
traveling = True
meters_second = 0
max_meters_second = 90
seconds = 0

accelerating = True
accel_distance = 0

# can change interval here
seconds_per_intervul = 1

while traveling:
    # end travel
    if meters <= 0:
        traveling = False
        meters = 0
        meters_second = 0
        seconds = 0
        print('you have arrived!')
        break
    # if distance to de accelerate < max distance
    elif meters < accel_distance:
        meters_second -= 1

    # if crossed half way while still accelerating
    elif (distance > max_diatance/2) and (accelerating == True):
        accelerating = False
        accel_distance = distance

    # else if reached max speed
    elif meters_second >= max_meters_second:
        if accelerating == True:
            accel_distance = distance - meters_second * seconds_per_intervul
            accelerating = False
        # peak speed
        meters_second = max_meters_second

    # else keep accelerating
    else:
        meters_second+=1


    # calc movement over interval
    distance += meters_second * seconds_per_intervul
    meters -= meters_second * seconds_per_intervul
    seconds += seconds_per_intervul
    print(f'dist to destination(m):{meters} M/s: {meters_second} time passed(s):{seconds}')
    time.sleep(seconds_per_intervul)
```

In this code I am assuming your goal is to reach a speed of 0 m/s at the same time you reach your destination as that falls within "realistic acceleration and deceleration". What this dose is track how far it took for the object to get to max speed, and then uses that distance to check when to stop accelerating. It also starts slowing down properly if it reached the half way point before reaching max speed.

Note that this still ends with some speed as it doesn't perfectly get the distance needed to deaccelerate because of both the large update interval, if you want prefect accuracy you are going to need to do math instead of just checking the relative distance every second. The formula is `accel_diatance = max_meters_second**2 / (2*acceleration)`. You still can't stop exactly at 0 though because you would need to check the distance at an infinitely short interval to not miss the exact moment where you are at 0. For practical purposes you can either accept stopping with some amount of speed (like I did here), or you round the distance so you stop when when you are say within 0.1m and update significantly more frequently.

Accelerating for a hard coded length of time doesn't work if you want to use variable distances, and even then you have an issue in your implementation. Your code accelerates for 20 seconds, then jumps to the max speed of 10000m/s, which doesn't match your goal of realistic acceleration. Your code also doesn't slow down fast enough simply because the half way point is too short of a distance to deaccelerate from the max speed you set.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer helps me understand the solution to the problem as it is a bit simpler than the other answer, but I will study them both to understand the core method to getting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you another way i use in some animations.

**This is a way to maintain time to go from A to B while trajectory can have acceleration and deceleration.**

Rather than trying to change speed, this change time estimation : as real time goes on, estimated time goes slowly or quickly.

Let's see :
First don't change time so it will run at a constant speed :

```
def functionOfTime(t):
    return t # no change

# A to B
meters = 100000 
# find and expected duration 
expectedDuration = 10 # seconds for travel 
# now calculate each point 
seconds = 0.0 
lastPercent = 0
print("seconds elapsed estima. position percent  delta") # for demo
while (seconds <= expectedDuration):
    elapsedTimeRatio = (seconds/expectedDuration)
    estimatedTimeRatio = functionOfTime(elapsedTimeRatio)
    position = meters* estimatedTimeRatio
    # for explicit traces
    positionPerCent= (position/meters)*100
    deltaPercent = positionPerCent - lastPercent
    lastPercent = positionPerCent 
    print ('{:4}______{:04.2f}_____{:04.2f}___{:06.0f}m__{:04.1f}%___+{:04.3f}%   '\
        .format(seconds,elapsedTimeRatio,estimatedTimeRatio,position,positionPerCent,deltaPercent))

    #Increment time here 1 for demo. Use smaller intervals 
    seconds+=1
```

Now notice that elapsedTimeRatio is a value between 0 and 1.
It's a main advantage: if you use any functionOfTime that stays between 0 and 1, you can go from A to B in same time T, but with speed changes.

In the following picture, the white line is the travel at constant speed of the upper code.

In green elapsedTimeRatio is transformed in estimatedTimeRatio by setting the first to power of 2, of 3, of 4 etc:

```
def functionOfTime(t):
    return t**2      #or t**3 t**4 for green curves
```

In green it starts slowly and finish quickly. This is one kind of animation.

In red elapsedTimeRatio is transformed in a symetric way by :

```
def functionOfTime(t):
    return 1- (1-t)**2 # or **3 **4 for red curves
```

In this red animation, it starts quickly and end slowly.

[image]

In fact, you can use any function f(x) that stays between 0..1 when x stays between 0..1 (power, sin, cos, your function ,etc. )

**MORE**.
What is important is not the side of the curve, but its slope against the medium.
Another curve, more relative to your question is a sigmoïde where **movement starts slowly, accelerate up to full speed then slow down.**

[image]

using GFE on line and playing with coefficients you can design different accelerations.
In the sample, to be at half trajectory at half time, use the blue curve with a = 16 and b = 0.7.

Now the function used for estimatedTimeRatio is :

```
import math
def functionOfTime(t):
    a = 16
    b= 0.7
    estimatedT = 1- (1/(1+math.exp(a*(-b/2+t/(2*b)))))
    return estimatedT
```

To verify, with a large step of 1 second to have few values, look at the display of *elapsedTime, estimatedTime, position (calculated with estimatedTime at elapsedTime seconds), percent of trajectory, increment of percent*

[image]
HTH

Comment: Thank you, I can tell you really thought this one out. I have been running your code and playing around with it to try to understand it better. This accomplishes what I want to achieve, but as I still don't understand it I will continue to work on it until I do.